# "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time..." with hashValue

Tags: swift, hash, compiler-errors

Trying to make my whole data model hashable, e.g....

```
let id:Int
let projectID:Int
let parentID:Int
let name:String
let description:String
let url:String
let startOn:Date?
let startedOn:Date?
let dueOn:Date?
let completedOn:Date?
let isStarted:Bool
let isCompleted:Bool

var hashValue:Int
{
    return (31 &* id.hashValue)
            &+ projectID.hashValue
            &+ parentID.hashValue
            &+ name.hashValue
            &+ description.hashValue
            &+ url.hashValue
            &+ (startOn != nil ? startOn!.hashValue: 0)
            &+ (startedOn != nil ? startedOn!.hashValue: 0)
            &+ (dueOn != nil ? dueOn!.hashValue: 0)
            &+ (completedOn != nil ? completedOn!.hashValue: 0)
            &+ isStarted.hashValue
            &+ isCompleted.hashValue
}
```

And I get compile error:

> Error:(112, 5) expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable
>   time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct
>   sub-expressions

Therefore the question: how do you make objects hashable where the hash depends on many properties? I have some model objects that have 3-4 times the amount of above properties.

Comment: Did you try what the compiler suggests, i.e. breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions ?

Comment: Note that `(startOn != nil ? startOn!.hashValue: 0)` can be more elegantly expressed as `(startOn?.hashValue ?? 0)`

Comment: Btw: If you make the `Date?` properties non-optional, then in Swift 4.1 the *compiler* can auto-generate the hash function for you, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your expression in multiple part and add all of them by appending in next addition

```
var hashValue:Int
    {
        let firstFrg =  (31 &* id.hashValue)
                &+ projectID.hashValue
                &+ parentID.hashValue
                &+ name.hashValue
        let secondFrg = firstFrg + &+ description.hashValue
                &+ url.hashValue
                &+ (startOn != nil ? startOn!.hashValue: 0)
        let thirdFrg = secondFrg + &+ (startedOn != nil ? startedOn!.hashValue: 0)
                &+ (dueOn != nil ? dueOn!.hashValue: 0)
                &+ (completedOn != nil ? completedOn!.hashValue: 0)
        let fourthFrg = thirdFrg + &+ isStarted.hashValue
                &+ isCompleted.hashValue

         return fourthFrg
    }
```

Comment: Ok, that's what the compiler had in mind! Not exactly elegant but if it's the only way to go...

Comment: On a related note ... is there anything that can be done against the insane increase in compile time if there are many longer Hashable methods? My build just went from ~1min to ~10mins with that.

Comment: ... also, now that I have several of my model classes implemented with broken-up hashable methods the compilation takes very long and then fails with the following errors: `Error:unable to execute command: Killed: 9, Error:compile command failed due to signal 9 (use -v to see invocation)`